# issue with auto height in coda slider 2

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

i'm using coda slider 2 for wrap some content

http://gidzior.net/coda/#3

i'm trying to auto height coda panel after click blue areas

i'm using jQuery code below ('p.legend') is a blue area:

```
$('p.legend').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass('down');
    // click in current coda tab for auto height
    $('#coda-nav-1 a.current').click();
});
```

coda slider - `$('#project-slider').codaSlider();`

but as you see in my example something odd is happening, what is wrong ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/X4agv/ My guess is it's because you're toggling `down`, instead of detecting and adjusting to the actual new height. So it gets wildly out of sync.

Comment: thanks for the example Jared, do u have any suggestions how to fix it ?? Maybe some auto click in 'a.current' after click function () is finish ??

Comment: Here's another update, fixing some of your code and markup formatting; you were missing a closing `</div>` tag at the very end, btw.

Comment: "another update" ??  am i missing something ??  http://jsfiddle.net/X4agv/2/ - i have an error here